# Checkbox default not matching state

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, checkbox

I want to have a checkbox with a defaultChecked value matching the value in my database. My current issue is that defaultChecked is always false, even when the database value is true.

Here is my current thinking + code:

I store the defaultChecked as a state:

`const [defaultEnabled, setDefaultEnabled] = useState(false);`

I then use a useEffect hook to read from the database once at the start of the page loading.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchEnabled = async () => {
      const reference = ref(db, 'Permissions/');
      onValue(reference, (snapshot) => {
        setDefaultEnabled(snapshot.val());
        // This read to the database works - that is, snapshot.val() does indeed return the correct boolean value
      });
    };

    fetchEnabled();
  }, []);
```

And lastly I have the checkbox itself [the handleChecked function works and does not effect the state].

`<input type='checkbox' onChange={handleChecked} defaultChecked={defaultEnabled}/>`

I suspect the issue comes from the useState(false) at the start, but my understanding was that when the useEffect is ran, it would update the state, and this would cause the checkbox to re-render with the correct value.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: There is not enough code, the error seems somewhere else, pls put full component code

Comment: This is the only code that interacts with the checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `defaultChecked` needs a value at the first moment it's rendered, and so it uses the initial `useState` value of false instead of waiting for the useEffect.

This can be solved by doing `checked={defaultEnabled}`, since the state will update this non-default checked attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can install yn library and set state as like as below.

1. npm install yn
2. setDefaultEnabled(yn(snapshot.val()));

Comment: This did not work. I don't think this is the issue, since the value is stored in the database as a boolean, not a string, so there is no need to parse it.